# Why am I geting wrong results in my array with I iterate?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am iterating on a array within a Object van. I am trying to pop the elements of the array into another object array. See below.

```
@van.bikes.each { @garage<<( @van.removebike )}

def removebike
   @bikes.pop   
end
```

When I do this the resulting array in the garage has missing elements and/or duplicate elements.

Comment: Could you also provide the class structure?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that when ruby iterates on the array it  sets number of iterations based on the original array size. When you pop an element from that array the size changes so the iteration can not work properly.

You can use instead,

```
@van.bikes.count.times { @garage<<( @van.removebike )}
```

Comment: Or just `@garage += @van.bikes; @van.bikes = []` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too..

```
@garage = []
@van.bikes.each{|bike| @garage << bike}
```